# What is the intended alternative to data-* attributes for independent software?

Tags: html, schema.org, rdfa

Reading [about the `data-*` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) in HTML 5:

> “These attributes are not intended for use by software that is dependent of the site that uses the attributes.”
>
> “User agents must not derive any implementation behavior from these attributes or values. Specifications intended for user agents must not define these attributes to have any meaningful values.”

Fair enough. So. What is the “intended” replacement for the excluded situations?

Say I’m making a software that needs to store some invisible data in the document. Its actually just one extra attribute that is added on an existing and established meta element. Hopefully, it would even be useful to more than just my software later down the line.

It doesn’t seem worth the effort to create and maintain a custom schema vocabulary, and quadruple the amount of markup required to include some extra info. I don’t like all the vendor specific mata elements like `apple-touch-icon` and the like, so I thought I’d ask the community before going down this way for my own software.

Specifically I’m trying to mark up payment methods for an entity (author and publisher meta element):

```
<meta content="Donald Duck"
      name="author"
      data-payable-bitcoin="3bafbaf"
      data-payable-paypal="merchantidstring">
```

The schema.org vocabulary for payment methods don’t really apply as there is no offer or anything this can be a payment method to. It’s just identifies how the author/publisher can be paid [voluntarily] It’s just identifying how an entity can be paid. The [nearest available vocabulary](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1.html) is very limited and only support a handful of **offensively US centric** payment providers and options.